# How do I get `HTML > Body > Background-Color > Transparent`?

Tags: html, css, background, background-color, opacity

I have this `HTML`:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
        <div style="width:100%; color:#000000; padding:25px; font-family: Segoe UI;font-size: 17px;">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have set the background-color with `bgcolor="#FFFFFF"`. But how do I make this transparent?

Comment: Transparent ?? is it white or you wan to make that color thin ?? if so there is an property called opacity, try that out

Comment: Maybe it is time for you to look into [stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/).

Comment: Just remove that attribute.. i.e `bgcolor`

Answer (score 9):

HTML provides no means to specify a transparent background (and the means it has to specify backgrounds of any kind are obsolete and should not be used). You can do this in CSS.

```
body { 
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

This will make the background  of the `<html>` element visible.

There is no way to make the browser window transparent.

Comment: "There is no way to make the browser window transparent."... **and even if there were...what would you expect to see on the other side.** :)

Comment: whatever was underneath the window on your OS :)

Comment: I can think of a use-case for this: when taking a screenshot with Chrome headless Selenium web driver, for instance, I'd like to have the resulting PNG transparent (apart from the visible elements).

Comment: I can think of another use-case for this: When making the `popup.html` for a Chrome extension. This is the bit of html that is displayed when clicking on the button added by your extension to the browser (next to the address bar). I have tried to round the edges but the corners of a white box are now visible. I want this transparent. Unfortunately, this solution does not do that.

Comment: @Paulie_D, Streaming software like OBS is now able to use transparent backgrounds, very useful for dynamic overlays in html, js and css.

Answer (score 3):

With inline-styling you can achieve this with:

```
<body style="background-color: transparent;">
```

But a better option is to put the following code:

```
body { background-color:transparent; }
```

in a CSS file which you link to in the `<head>` section of the page like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="NAMEOFFILE.css">
```

Comment: I just need to add `body { background-color:transparent; }` inside `head` tag right ?

Comment: @user2056563 this code will only make it transparent relatively to the elements 'behind' it, i.e. the `<html>` tag.

Comment: @user2056563 — No. Read the first four words of the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: I dont have any css file, but can we add in head section ? can you please show me how , as i am new here

Comment: @user2056563 — Since you are trying to influence the appearance of a webpage, you should do.

Comment: Go and look up any basic CSS tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

```
background-color: transparent;
```

**Update**
However, you HAVE NO WAY to make the browser window transparent. So, even if you use the code above, your background will still be white.

Comment: where do i need to add ?

Comment: Preferably in a CSS file you link to in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: in the body style, or in a separate css file.

Comment: This constitutes a style attribute of the `body` element in your mark-up. As an aside, I would suggest moving all your style directives into a separate stylesheet and link to that rather than spattering your mark-up with in-line styling directives.

Comment: Yea but consider a HTML loaded in a iframe. That HTML inside an iframe with body transparent works and it doesn't paint the BG color at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CSS instead of HTML attributes to set transparent background:

```
<body style="background: transparent; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
```

Preferably you should have a style sheet for the page where you put the styles instead of putting styles in the HTML elements.

Note: To have an iframe with a transparent background (which is the only way that a transparent background on a page can be used) you need to add the `allowtransparency` attribute to the iframe tag for it to work in IE:

```
<iframe .... allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: None of that will make the Browser Window transparent the `html` will still default to a white background, it's just not doable without manipulating the window using the Windows GDI and even then I imagine it wouldn't be easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {

    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
};
```

last value is alpha - it will set transparency values between 0 and 1; 0 transparent;

Answer (score 0):

Use
`body{background:none transparent;}`
or
`<body style="background:none transparent;">`
There is no need for `allowtransparency ="true"` in your iframe.