# I want to make a transparent window with css

Tags: html, css, background, transparent, workspace

I know that is possible to make a div with transparent background. But I haven't how to do a body with transparent background, because its background stay white.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='background:transparent'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to know if exist some way to makes body really transparent (showing my workspace).

Comment: How do you imagine a transparent background for the body?

Comment: it has nothing to do with css, it has to do with the program itself (here the browsers) .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML body bgcolor transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564182/html-body-bgcolor-transparent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make `<body>` tag `transparent`, Because there should be a default or a base color to use it as a transparent color.
So as a verdict you make `<body>` tag confused, Like he says whats my `transparent` color to use it? if there's not browser uses default color.
and i guess this post is duplicate.
[HTML body bgcolor transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564182/html-body-bgcolor-transparent)

Answer (score 1):

You can't make the body transparent.
Imagine this, what color would be behind if the body becomes transparent? They only way to know if something is transparent is if there's another color behind. The body has no styleable parent element so you can't expect to remove its own base color.
Let me know if this is clear.